# Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent

Tags: php, http-headers

Below is a simple example of my PHP code which (I hope so) is self explanatory. What I try to do is to update the session variable. But the output of the script is as follows:

> Warning: session_start()
> [function.session-start]: Cannot send
> session cookie - headers already sent
> by (output started at
> /Library/WebServer/Documents/facebook/test.php:8)
> in
> /Library/WebServer/Documents/facebook/test.php
> on line 11

The warning is caused by the `echo` statements in line 8 and 9, of course. Is there any simple solution to stop this warning?

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['percent'] = 0;
$iterations = 50;
    
for ($i = 0; $i <= iterations; $i++) {
  $percent = ($i / $iterations) * 100;
  echo "Hello World!";
  echo "<br />";
  // update session variable
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['percent'] = number_format($percent, 0, '', '');
  session_commit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to set cookies (or send any other headers) after output is started. You could add ob_start() at line 1 to buffer the output.

The right solution is to separate logic from the output. Check out e.g. 
http://www.paragoncorporation.com/ArticleDetail.aspx?ArticleID=21

Answer (score 4):

Remove the session_start() from inside the for loop.

Put the session_commit() outside the for loop at the very end.

Both these functions should only be called once in a script.

Comment: Altho, you are overwriting the same session variable. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Reproduce this (look at process.php file): http://q2interactive.net/view/how-to-build-an-ajax-progress-bar-with-jquery-and-php.html

Comment: Ahh, that was my guess. If you are trying to reproduce that then take out the echo statements.

Comment: session_start() needs to send a HTTP header to send a cookie. It can't do that if any other content has already been sent. So your only 2 answers are 1) take out the echo statements or 2) use output buffering, as you noted.

Comment: The idea behind my code is to print the elements of an array (not included in the example above) and show the progress using the progress bar.

Comment: Well if you absolutely must print output as you go you can't use PHP sessions. Look to storing the progress variable elsewhere, like in a DB or a common memory cache or a file or something. Altho this must be a really really big array if it needs a progress bar just to print, are you sure this whole approach is the right one?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any previeus output before the session-start() statement,then try to resave your .php file as an ansi-file or as utf-8 without BOM file.
that's bc in some cases the editor itself writes things as an output in the file.

It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute the `session_start()` function only once. So just drop the one within the loop.

Also you don't have to do the `session_commit()` manually, in most cases PHP handles this for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have stated, the cause of the error is the second `session_start()` you are using. However, the actual reason it's throwing an error is because you are trying to set a header after you've already sent output. Since the session_start() function sets the session cookie, it tried to set the cookie header, which is after you already echo content.