# PHP session_start(): Cannot send session cookie

Tags: php, session

`session_start();` is the first thing I call. There is no whitespace. Why am I still get this warning?

**Screenshots:**

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Error:**

> [20-Feb-2014 16:52:32 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send         session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/feyzprod/public_html/expertlookup.ca/index.php:1) in /home/feyzprod/public_html/expertlookup.ca/index.php on line 4
>
> [20-Feb-2014 16:52:32 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/feyzprod/public_html/expertlookup.ca/index.php:1) in /home/feyzprod/public_html/expertlookup.ca/index.php on line 4

```
<?php session_start();  

    require_once('bdservice.php');
    $bd = new BDService();
    require_once('script.php');

    if(!isset($_SESSION['specialiteBD']))
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Specialites";

        try
        { $resultat = $bd->Select($sql); }
        catch(Exception $e)
        { echo $e->getMessage(); }

        if(count($resultat) != 0)
        {
            $newSpec= array();
            foreach($resultat as $a)
            {
                $newSpec[] = utf8_encode($a[1]);
            }

            $_SESSION['specialiteBD'] = $newSpec;           
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<title>Annuaire</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ico.css" />
<script src='js/validation.js'></script>
<script>
   function initialize()
   {
        var input = document.getElementById('where');
        var componentRestrictions = {country: 'ca'};
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions(componentRestrictions);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

     $(function() {
    var availableTags = [];
    var ville = [];

    var availableTags = <?php echo urldecode(json_encode($_SESSION['specialiteBD'])) ?>;

    for(var i = 0; i < availableTags.length; i++)
    {
        ville.push(decode(availableTags[i]));
    }
    $( "#what" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
       source: function(req, responseFn) {
        var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
        var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + re, "i" );
        var a = $.grep( ville, function(item,index){
            return matcher.test(item);
        });
        responseFn( a.slice(0,10));
    }
    });
  });
</script>
 </head>

 <body>
<?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>
    <div class='headerBar'>
        <div class='headerContent'>
            <div id='logo'><a href='index.php'><img src='images/logo4.png' height='75' width='321' alt="Expert LookUp"/ title="Expert LookUp"/></a></div>
            <div id='navLien'>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span>
                                <?php
                                    if(isset($_SESSION['authentification']))
                                    {
                                        echo "<a href='logout.php'>déconnexion</a>
                                                   <a href='profil.php' class='blue_Button'>Profil</a>";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo "<a href='enregistrement.php'>Ajouter votre entreprise</a>
                                                   <a href='connexion.php' class='blue_Button'>Connexion</a>";
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='blur'>
        <div class='blurContent'>
            <div id='left'>
                <p>Multiplier votre visibilité sur le web en vous inscrivant gratuitement sur notre moteur de recherche d'entreprise.</p>
                    <a href='enregistrement.php' class='blue_Button'>S'enregistrer</a>
            </div>
            <div id='right'>
                <form action='search/index.php' method='get'>
                <p>Trouvez un entrepreneur pour vos prochains travaux</p>
                <div class='iconMan'><input type='text' name='what' id='what' size='40' placeholder="Que recherchez vous ? Ex : Plombier" required title="Veuillez indiquer votre critère de recherche." x-moz-errormessage="Veuillez indiquer votre critère de recherche." /></div><br/>
                <?php
                    if(isset($_SESSION['invalideAdr']))
                    {
                        unset($_SESSION['invalideAdr']);
                        echo "<div class='iconWhere'><input type='text' style=\"border:1px solid red;\" name='where' id='where' size='40' placeholder=\"Impossible de trouver votre adresse !\" required title=\"Veuillez indiquer l\'emplacement de vos travaux.\" x-moz-errormessage=\"Veuillez indiquer l\'emplacement de vos travaux.\" /></div><br/>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<div class='iconWhere'><input type='text' name='where' id='where' size='40' required title=\"Veuillez indiquer l\'emplacement de vos travaux.\" x-moz-errormessage=\"Veuillez indiquer l\'emplacement de vos travaux.\" /></div><br/>";
                    }
                ?>
                <div class='radio'>
                    <input type="radio" id="r1" name="secteur" value='1' />
                    <label for="r1"><span></span>Résidentiel</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="r2" name="secteur" value='2' />
                    <label for="r2"><span></span>Industriel</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="r3" name="secteur" value='3' checked="checked" />
                    <label for="r3"><span></span>Les deux</label><br/><br/>
                    <input type='hidden' name='page' value='1' />
                    <input type='submit' name='Rechercher' value='Rechercher' class='blue_Button' />
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='infoContent'>

        <div id='info'>
            <p>À propos d'Expert Lookup</p>
            <span style='font-weight:bold;'>Information</span><br/>
            <span>Expert LookUp est un annuaire se concentra principalement sur les entreprises dans le domaine de la construction.</span><br/><br/>
            <span style='font-weight:bold;'>La simplicité même !</span><br/>
            <span>Vous avez uniquement à choisir quel type d'entreprises/personnes vous recherchez, l'emplacement de votre travaux et le secteur d'activité pour faire votre recherche.
            Les résultats de recherches vous seront affichées par ordre de distance et si une entreprise ne se déplace pas jusqu`à chez vous, elle ne sera pas affichée.</span><br/><br/>
            <span style='font-weight:bold;'>Validation de la licence RBQ</span><br/>
            <span>Nous vérifions directement à partir de la base de données de Gouvernement du Québec pour vérifier la licence RBQ des entreprises enregistrées sur notre annuaires.
             Si une entreprise ne dispose pas de licence RBQ valide, cette information vous sera affichée.</span><br/><br/>
        </div>

        <div id='why'>
            <p>Pourquoi s'enregistrer ?</p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>Soyez visible partout au Canada, auprès des millions d'internautes !</span></td>
                    <td><img src='images/blueEarth.png' width='97' height='97' alt='terre' title='terre' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>Expert LookUp est un annuaire entièrement gratuit, aucun frais caché !</span></td>
                    <td><img src='images/greenMoney.png' width='97' height='97' alt='terre' title='terre' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>Votre inscription prendra  moins de 5 minutes, alors qu'attendez-vous ? Vous n'avez rien à perdre !</span></td>
                    <td><img src='images/clock.png' width='97' height='97' alt='terre' title='terre' /></td>
                </tr>               
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class='footerBar'>
        <div class='footerContent'>
            <a href='contact.php'>Contactez-nous</a><span> | </span>
            <a href='enregistrement.php'>Ajouter votre entreprise</a><span> | </span>
            <a href='connexion.php'>Connexion</a><span> | </span>
            <a href='aide.php'>Aide</a><br/>
            <span>&#169; Copyright at ExpertLookUp.ca</span>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Can you just copy your code in?

Comment: It says "encoding: utf8".  Is there a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) in the file?  P.S. Paste your code, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: it says the error is on line 4. line 4 is a require_once statement. what's happening with that other script?

Comment: @skrilled: It's `session_start()` in the first screenshot.  Not sure why there are 2 screenshots.

Comment: Yeah it's for the first screenshot, i removed the second one. I added the code.

Comment: Just a side note, you dont need to check if the session is started or not `if(!isset($_SESSION)){...}` If a session already exists, it will use the existing session instead of creating a new one. As per the documentation here: http://us1.php.net/session_start , it says `session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request...`

Comment: Used notePad++ to convert all my file to utf-8 without BOM, its working now but my site is bugged now can not use accent 'é'

Comment: Why are you doing `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />`?  Try `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

Comment: i guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523363/cannot-send-session-cookie-headers-already-sent will help you

Answer (score 1):

No need to check if your `session_start()` has already started or not. `session_start()` will just use the current session if there is one.

PHP Doc:

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on
>   a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a
>   cookie.

[Link](http://www.php.net/session_start)

About the error you're receiving, I'm guessing this is due to the `IF-Statement` lines above it.

Answer (score -5):

Well, that is probably because you already started session somewhere. I usually made solution by putting `@` before `session_start` and error was silent and session also worked.

So, `@session_start();` may be solution.

Comment: Not usually a good idea to suppress warnings/errors. PHP is flagging those issues for a reason...